# Como calcular hora de saída com base na hora de entrada

Tags: php

Estou a tentar fazer um sistema de ponto simples em PHP somente para calcular a hora de saída com base na hora que eu entrar. Por exemplo, meu horário de entrada é as 07:00 e saída as 16:48 o que eu quero fazer é colocar o horário que eu entro e mostrar a hora que deveria sair.

Exemplo: se eu entrar as 06:30 eu entrei 30 minutos mais cedo, então eu teria que sair as 16:18, então teria que diminuir 30 minutos da variável $saida, mais não consigo achar uma lógica para fazer isso.

HTML

```html
<form  action="dashboard.php?link=home" method="post"  class="ajax_off">
    <div class='row'>  
        <div class="col col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hr_entrada" value="07:00:00">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-8">
          <div class='row'><button  class="btn btn-icon btn-primary">Calcular</button></div>                    </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```php
$Entrada = (isset($_POST['hr_entrada']) ? $_POST['hr_entrada'] : '07:00:00');
$Saida =  '16:48:00';

Echo 'voce deve sair as '.$Saida;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não pense sobre as diferenças de horário. Pense no intervalo que você precisa trabalhar. Pela sua descrição, são 588 minutos. Sendo assim, o seguinte código PHP pode ser usado:

```php
$horario = new DateTime(isset($_POST['hr_entrada']) ? $_POST['hr_entrada'] : '07:00');
$horario->add(new DateInterval('PT588M'));

echo 'voce deve sair as ' . $horario->format('H:i');
```

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer cálculos de horas com `php`  utilizo a função `strtotime()`;

Cada parâmetro desta função utiliza o fuso horário padrão do servidor.

```
$duration = array('hours' => 9, 'minutes' => 48);

$entrance =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$leave =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",  strtotime("+{$duration['hours']} hours {$duration['minutes']} minutes", strtotime($entrance) ) );

echo "Entrada: {$entrance} <br> Saida: {$leave}";
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta consegui resolver